# Flutter Local Notifications - Progaurd Rules does not allow to build release version

Tags: flutter, flutter-local-notification

I am using flutter_local_notifications in one of my app and I set up the progaurd-rules.pro according to the doc.

> android/app/progaurd-rules.pro

```
## Gson rules
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-dontwarn sun.misc.**
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Prevent proguard from stripping interface information from TypeAdapter, TypeAdapterFactory,
# JsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer instances (so they can be used in @JsonAdapter)
-keep class * extends com.google.gson.TypeAdapter
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer

# Prevent R8 from leaving Data object members always null
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
  @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}

-keep class com.dexterous.** { *; }
```

With this, I can run the debug version just as fine. However, when building release build, I get the exceptions:

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
ERROR:: R8: com.android.tools.r8.errors.b: Attribute Signature requires InnerClasses attribute. Check -keepattributes directive.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'.
> com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s
[!] The shrinker may have failed to optimize the Java bytecode.
    To disable the shrinker, pass the `--no-shrink` flag to this command.
    To learn more, see: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code
Exception: Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Now, I do not want to use the "--no-shrink". Any idea whats wrong in my progaurd-rules.pro file?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue myself. Adding `-keepattributes InnerClasses` to the file fixed the issue.

> Updated Progaurd:

```
## Gson rules
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes InnerClasses
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-dontwarn sun.misc.**
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Prevent proguard from stripping interface information from TypeAdapter, TypeAdapterFactory,
# JsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer instances (so they can be used in @JsonAdapter)
-keep class * extends com.google.gson.TypeAdapter
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer

# Prevent R8 from leaving Data object members always null
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
  @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}

-keep class com.dexterous.** { *; }
```